# Only my last subplot shows when accessing GUI through handle

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a function which is display the readings from a device onto my GUI. At the moment there is a problem where only the last subplot is showing within the GUI figure, in the GUI it self it shows blank space (no axes and graphing data) where the three other plots should be. The 4th subplot shows perfectly with all data. I've tested this function without using data from the device and launching a figure (not in GUI) from within the function it self shows all the subplots.

axes1 is my axes tag in the GUI.

```
function  BioRadioData = BioRadio_Stream2( myDevice , duration , BioRadio_Name , axes1 )


numEnabledBPChannels = double(myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.Count);

if numEnabledBPChannels == 0
    myDevice.Disconnect;
    BioRadioData = [];
    errordlg('No BioPotential Channels Programmed. Return to BioCapture to Configure.')
    return
end

sampleRate_BP = double(myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.SamplesPerSecond);
sampleRate_Pod = 250;

axis_handles = zeros(1,numEnabledBPChannels);
disp(axis_handles)
disp(length(axis_handles))
for ch = 1:numEnabledBPChannels
    axis_handles(ch) = subplot(length(axis_handles),1,ch,axes1);
    disp(ch)
    if ch==1
        title(char(BioRadio_Name))
    end
    ylabel([char(myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.Item(ch-1).Name) ' (V)']);
    hold(axes1,'on')
end

xlabel('Time (s)')

linkaxes(axis_handles,'x')


BioPotentialSignals = cell(1,numEnabledBPChannels);

myDevice.StartAcquisition;

plotWindow = 5;

plotGain_BP = 1;

elapsedTime = 0;
tic;

while elapsedTime < duration
    pause(0.08)
    for ch = 1:numEnabledBPChannels
        BioPotentialSignals{ch} = [BioPotentialSignals{ch};myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.Item(ch-1).GetScaledValueArray.double'];
        if length(BioPotentialSignals{ch}) <= plotWindow*sampleRate_BP
            cla(axis_handles(ch))
            t = (0:(length(BioPotentialSignals{ch})-1))*(1/sampleRate_BP);
            plot(axis_handles(ch),t,plotGain_BP*BioPotentialSignals{ch});
            xlim([0 plotWindow])
        else
            if ch==1
                t = ((length(BioPotentialSignals{ch})-(plotWindow*sampleRate_BP-1)):length(BioPotentialSignals{ch}))*(1/sampleRate_BP);
            end
            cla(axis_handles(ch))
            plot(axis_handles(ch),t,plotGain_BP*BioPotentialSignals{ch}(end-plotWindow*sampleRate_BP+1:end));
            xlim([t(end)-plotWindow t(end)])
        end
    end

    elapsedTime = elapsedTime + toc;
    tic;
end

myDevice.StopAcquisition;

BioRadioData = cell(1,1);
BioRadioData{1} = BioPotentialSignals;

end
```

This code segment below works but produces a seperate figure to the GUI created. While the above code produces only the 4th plot within the GUI.

```
function  BioRadioData = BioRadio_Stream2( myDevice , duration , BioRadio_Name )



    numEnabledBPChannels = double(myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.Count);

    if numEnabledBPChannels == 0
        myDevice.Disconnect;
        BioRadioData = [];
        errordlg('No BioPotential Channels Programmed. Return to BioCapture to Configure.')
        return
    end

    sampleRate_BP = double(myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.SamplesPerSecond);
    sampleRate_Pod = 250;

    axis_handles = zeros(1,numEnabledBPChannels);
    disp(axis_handles)
    disp(length(axis_handles))
    figure
    for ch = 1:numEnabledBPChannels
        %axis_handles(ch) = subplot(length(axis_handles),1,ch,axes1);
        axis_handles(ch) = subplot(length(axis_handles),1,ch);
        disp(ch)
        if ch==1
            title(char(BioRadio_Name))
        end
        ylabel([char(myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.Item(ch-1).Name) ' (V)']);
        %hold(axes1,'on')
        hold on
    end

    disp(axis_handles)
    disp(length(axis_handles))
    disp(ch)

    xlabel('Time (s)')

    linkaxes(axis_handles,'x')


    BioPotentialSignals = cell(1,numEnabledBPChannels);

    myDevice.StartAcquisition;

    plotWindow = 5;

    plotGain_BP = 1;

    elapsedTime = 0;
    tic;

    while elapsedTime < duration
        pause(0.08)
        for ch = 1:numEnabledBPChannels
            BioPotentialSignals{ch} = [BioPotentialSignals{ch};myDevice.BioPotentialSignals.Item(ch-1).GetScaledValueArray.double'];
            if length(BioPotentialSignals{ch}) <= plotWindow*sampleRate_BP
                cla(axis_handles(ch))
                t = (0:(length(BioPotentialSignals{ch})-1))*(1/sampleRate_BP);
                plot(axis_handles(ch),t,plotGain_BP*BioPotentialSignals{ch});
                hold(axis_handles(ch),'on')
                xlim([0 plotWindow])
            else
                if ch==1
                    t = ((length(BioPotentialSignals{ch})-(plotWindow*sampleRate_BP-1)):length(BioPotentialSignals{ch}))*(1/sampleRate_BP);
                end
                cla(axis_handles(ch))
                plot(axis_handles(ch),t,plotGain_BP*BioPotentialSignals{ch}(end-plotWindow*sampleRate_BP+1:end));
                hold(axis_handles(ch),'on')
                xlim([t(end)-plotWindow t(end)])
            end
        end

        elapsedTime = elapsedTime + toc;
        tic;
    end

    myDevice.StopAcquisition;

    BioRadioData = cell(1,1);
    BioRadioData{1} = BioPotentialSignals;

    end
```

Testing Data

```
function varargout = ProjectGUI5test(varargin)
% PROJECTGUI5TEST MATLAB code for ProjectGUI5test.fig
%      PROJECTGUI5TEST, by itself, creates a new PROJECTGUI5TEST or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = PROJECTGUI5TEST returns the handle to a new PROJECTGUI5TEST or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      PROJECTGUI5TEST('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in PROJECTGUI5TEST.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      PROJECTGUI5TEST('Property','Value',...) creates a new PROJECTGUI5TEST or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before ProjectGUI5test_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to ProjectGUI5test_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help ProjectGUI5test

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 01-Apr-2016 16:25:01

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @ProjectGUI5test_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @ProjectGUI5test_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before ProjectGUI5test is made visible.
function ProjectGUI5test_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to ProjectGUI5test (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for ProjectGUI5test
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes ProjectGUI5test wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = ProjectGUI5test_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in connectbutton.
function connectbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to connectbutton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles = guidata(hObject);
%loads handles into the function
BioRadioData = BioRadio_Stream3( 30 , handles.axes1 );


% --- Executes on button press in disconnectbutton.
function disconnectbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to disconnectbutton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function axes1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to axes1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: place code in OpeningFcn to populate axes1

function  BioRadioData = BioRadio_Stream3( duration , axes1 )
% function  BioRadioData = BioRadio_Stream( myDevice , duration , BioRadio_Name )
% BioRadio_Stream streams data from the BioRadio and imports it into MATLAB.
%
% INPUTS:
% - myDevice is a handle to a BioRadio device object
% - duration is the data collection interval in seconds
% - BioRadio_name is string containing the BioRadio name


numEnabledBPChannels = 4;


sampleRate_BP = 1000;

axis_handles = zeros(1,numEnabledBPChannels);


for ch = 1:numEnabledBPChannels
    axis_handles(ch) = subplot(length(axis_handles),1,ch,axes1);
    disp(ch)
    if ch==1
        title('Title')
    end
    ylabel(' (V)');
    hold(axes1,'on')
end



xlabel('Time (s)')

linkaxes(axis_handles,'x')

BioPotentialSignals = cell(1,numEnabledBPChannels);

plotWindow = 5;

plotGain_BP = 1;

elapsedTime = 0;
tic;

while elapsedTime < duration
    pause(0.08)
    for ch = 1:numEnabledBPChannels
        BioPotentialSignals{ch} = [BioPotentialSignals{ch};sin(t)];
        if length(BioPotentialSignals{ch}) <= plotWindow*sampleRate_BP
            cla(axis_handles(ch))
            t = (0:(length(BioPotentialSignals{ch})-1))*(1/sampleRate_BP);
            plot(axis_handles(ch),t,plotGain_BP*BioPotentialSignals{ch});
            hold(axis_handles(ch),'on')
            xlim([0 plotWindow])
        else
            if ch==1
                t = ((length(BioPotentialSignals{ch})-(plotWindow*sampleRate_BP-1)):length(BioPotentialSignals{ch}))*(1/sampleRate_BP);
            end
            cla(axis_handles(ch))
            plot(axis_handles(ch),t,plotGain_BP*BioPotentialSignals{ch}(end-plotWindow*sampleRate_BP+1:end));
            hold(axis_handles(ch),'on')
            xlim([t(end)-plotWindow t(end)])
        end
    end

    elapsedTime = elapsedTime + toc;
    tic;
end


BioRadioData = cell(1,1);
BioRadioData{1} = BioPotentialSignals;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the axis in your .fig, and add a uipanel instead.

In the `connectbutton_Callback` function, you call BioRadio_Stream3. Send your uipanel as input instead of your former axes, like this:

```
BioRadio_Stream3( 30 , handles.uipanel1 );
```

in `function BioRadio_Stream3`, change `subplot(4,1,1,axes1);` to `subplot(4,1,1,'Parent',axes1);`

And the same for the other subplots.

Comment: This just made all the plot lines appear on 4th subplot. I think it may have something to do with the first for loop, clearing the other subplots

Comment: You call cla(axis_handles(ch)) at two instances, did you change both?

Comment: Also, could you not plot immediately after creating the subplots? If possible, do everything in the first loop.

Comment: Hey, I tried both of the methods. I updated my main post showing the working code below, the problem with the working code is that it doesn't produce the figure within the GUI. The only changes I made to the GUI code was to introduce the figures tag handle to the function.

Comment: Try to not create the subplots separately. Create the subplots when you plot.

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Did you check that the other plots actually plot something? If you are certain that something should be plotted, could create the same problem with a simpler piece of code, such that I can run it? That way I am sure I could find the problem.

Comment: I've added a simpler piece of code except it doesn't use the device, I'm not sure how to upload the fig file but its fairly basic only having the connect and disconnect button and one square axes, labelled with tag axes1. the connect button in the gui.m file has: handles = guidata(hObject);
%loads handles into the function
BioRadioData = BioRadio_Stream3( 30 , handles.axes1 );

Comment: Image showing the fig and what actually is produced using the testing code: http://imgur.com/ma2fqNL

Comment: This is what I get: http://imgur.com/evzhckz
However, BioPotentialSignals is empty and t is empty. So the plot command doesn't plot anything. But all your subplots should be created at least.

Comment: Yeah, you are getting four plots though somehow, what could that mean? it doesn't add up. I know I can get 4 plots when I don't use gui and just use figure command.

Comment: I've updated the testing code to include the automated functions created by the guide, can you check to see if yours is similar?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by changing the code:

```
for ch = 1:numEnabledBPChannels
    axis_handles(ch) = subplot(length(axis_handles),1,ch);
    disp(ch)
```

from

```
for ch = 1:numEnabledBPChannels
    axis_handles(ch) = subplot(length(axis_handles),1,ch,axes1);
    disp(ch)
```

Apparently matlab doesn't like it when you set the axes handle in the subplot command. Not sure why it doesn't like it, matlab docs shows examples of this being possible.

Comment: Yours works very well, thanks for the help, this was bugging me for so long. Still don't really understand why subplot doesn't take axes handle when in the matlab docs it shows it does!

Comment: I suppose they don't want an axis to be divided into more axes. But yeah, it shouldn't be a problem to make it possible :P Thanks for the upvote ;) Glad I could help!